# trying to find name on the basis of foreign keys

Tags: mysql

struggling in below situation

I have two tables cities and city_distance

Table cities structure:- **pkCityID CityName** values example **{(1, a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d)}**

city_distance structure:- **fkCityID fkCitiesID CityDistance** values **{(1, 2, 3.3), (1, 3, 4.1), (1, 4, 6.1)}** etc

*Note:- Both fkCityID and fkCitiesID are the foreign keys of pkCityID*

**What I need:- b c d**

Now I want to find all CityName of fkCitiesID on the basis of CityName. Means I know the CityName.

What I am doing:-

1. Find pkCityID on the basis of CityName
2. Find all CityNames with join.

Here City ID is 1 then query:-

```
SELECT CityName, d.fkCityID, d.fkCitiesID 
FROM city_distance as d inner
join cities as c on d.fkCitiesID = c.pkCityID WHERE fkCityID = 1
```

How can I do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join from cities to city_distance, and then **back** to cities:

```
Select cities_b.CityName
  From cities cities_a
  Join city_distance cd On cities_a.pkCityID = cd.fkCityID
  Join cities cities_b On cd.fkCitiesID = cities_b.pkCityID
 Where cities_a.CityName = 'a';
```

This should return `b, c, d`

(You say you want `a, b, c` in your question, but I'm assuming that's a typo since I can't see any pattern to it)

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c89912/2

Comment: Thanks, I will check now.

Comment: Opps, you made this so easy. Thanks